# Toggle lis to close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of li's in this mobile menu. I'm trying to get these li >a's to close when I click on them again. I got them to open fine with the 'show' class, but the div class doesn't close again when I click on it. Any idea what's going on?

I tried to get it to when on click go to the parent (the li) and the find the child named '.dropdown-submenu--dp-0' and then toggle the show class. But it doesn't toggle. Only adds.

```
<li id="menu-item-3291" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-3291 nav-item dropdown">
   <a href="/OrganicDirect" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle--submenu dropdown-toggle--submenu--dp-0">Solutions</a>

   <div class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-submenu--dp-0">
    <a href="/solutions" class="nav-link dropdown- 
     item">Identity Platform Overview</a>
   </div>
</li>

</div>
```

```
  $('.dropdown-toggle--submenu').on('click', function(e){

// to close all lis and then only open the one selected.
    $('.dropdown-toggle--submenu').each(function(){
      $('.dropdown-submenu').removeClass('show');

    })

// toggle show
   $(e.target).parent().find('.dropdown-submenu--dp-0').toggleClass('show');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(this)

see: https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(this).removeClass('show');
```

If you want to remove the class show.

However for toggling (inverse) visibility with jquery use https://api.jquery.com/toggle/
Or if you definetly want to hide the visible elements use https://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Sadly that doesnt work. I basically just need the 'show' class to toggle off when clicked to the .dropdown-submenu--dp-0. When clicked it goes on to the element, but doesnt go away.

Comment: @MPortman If your query selector for the each function is correct then my answer will work.